# Adding a new custom phtml block to the header

Tags: magento2, template, custom-block

How does one add a new block and template file to the header in Magento2?

So far I've created a child theme, which is working, including a `default.xml`, which is successfully moving other block around. But for creating a new block it won't work.

So far I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" before="-" />

    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <container name="custom.header" htmlClass="headerSitemenu" htmlTag="div">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/headersitemenu.phtml">

            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

and have created `headersitemenu.phtml` inside `<theme>/Magento_Theme/html`.

Flushed and cleaned the cache etc, but nothing shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong template file location it should be in

`<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/headersitemenu.phtml`

**Update**

block name **navigation.sections** already exist so you can't use change to some other name, block name should be unique. I reckon enable developer mode to get error details. logs are placed in `<magento-root>/var/log/*` check there you got any error related to **invalid template**.

if you would like to customize existing block, change `<block .....` to `<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">`

Comment: Thanks for catching that! It's still not showing up, but I clearly needed to fix that too!